# Implementing Singly Linked List

Tags: java

I am trying to learn data structure, but I ran into the dreaded `NullPointerException` and I am not sure how to fix it.

My `SinglyLinkedList<E>` class implements an interface, `LinkedList`, where I redefined some methods like, `add(), get(), contains()`, and more.

The `NullPointerException` happens when I use the `clear()` method. It points at the method `removeLast()` under `nodeBefore.setNext(null)`. It also points to the `clear()` method under `remove(head.getElement())`.

Also, if there is anything I can improve upon in my code please let me know.

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<E> implements LinkedList<E> {

    private class Node<E> {

        public Node<E> next;
        public E element;

        public Node(E element) {

            this.element = element;
        }

        public Node (E element, Node<E> next) {

            this.element = element;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public E getElement() {

            return element;
        }

        public Node<E> getNext() {

            return next;
        }

        public void setElement(E element) {

            this.element = element;
        }

        public void setNext(Node<E> next) {

            this.next = next;
        }

        public String toString() {

            return ("[" + element + "] ");
        }
    }

    public Node<E> head;
    public Node<E> tail;
    public int total;      

    public SinglyLinkedList() {

        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null; 
        this.total = 0;
    }

    public E get(int index) {

        if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (index == 0) {
            return head.getElement();
        }

        Node<E> singly = head.getNext();

        for (int i = 1; i < index; i ++) {

            if (singly.getNext() == null) {
              return null;
            }       

            singly = singly.getNext();      
        }

        System.out.println("\n" + singly.getElement());

        return singly.getElement(); 
    }

    public void add(E element) {
        Node<E> singlyAdd = new Node<E>(element);

        if (tail == null) {
            head = singlyAdd;
            tail = singlyAdd;
        } else {
            tail.setNext(singlyAdd);
            tail = singlyAdd;
        }     

        total++;
    }             

    public void display() {
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("empty list");
        } else {
            Node<E> current = head;
            while (current != null) {
                System.out.print(current.toString());
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean contains(E data) {

        if (head == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (head.getElement() == data) {
            System.out.println(head);
            return true;                                
        }

        while (head.getNext() != null) {
            head = head.getNext();

            if (head.getElement() == data) {
                System.out.println(head);                
                return true;                               
            }             

        } 

        return false;         
    }       

    private Node<E> removeFirst() {
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("We cant delete an empty list");
        }    

        Node<E> singly = head;            
        head = head.getNext();
        singly.setNext(null);
        total--;

        return singly;     
    } 

    private Node<E> removeLast() {

        Node<E> nodeBefore;
        Node<E> nodeToRemove;     

        if (size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Empty list");
        }    

        nodeBefore = head;

        for (int i = 0; i < size() - 2; i++) {
          nodeBefore = nodeBefore.getNext();
        }    

        nodeToRemove = tail;    

        nodeBefore.setNext(null);
        tail = nodeBefore;
        total--;

        return nodeToRemove;
    }       

    public E remove(int index) {      

        E hold = get(index);     

        if (index < 0 || index >= size()) {
            return null;
        } else if (index == 0) { 

            removeFirst();    
            return hold;
        } else {

            Node<E> current = head;
            for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {                
                current = current.getNext();
            }  

            current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
            total--; 
            return hold;
        }       
    }       

    public int size() {
        return getTotal();
    }

    public boolean remove(E data) {      

        Node<E> nodeBefore, currentNode; 

        if (size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Empty list");
        }            

        currentNode = head;

        if (currentNode.getElement() == data) {
            removeFirst();
        }

        currentNode = tail;
        if (currentNode.getElement() == data) {
            removeLast();
        }

        if (size() - 2 > 0) {
            nodeBefore = head;
            currentNode = head.getNext();
            for (int i = 0; i < size() - 2; i++) {
                if (currentNode.getElement() == data) {

                    nodeBefore.setNext(currentNode.getNext());
                    total--;
                    break;
                }

                nodeBefore = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
            } 
        } 

        return true;
    }

    public void clear() {

        while (head.getNext() != null) {    
            remove(head.getElement());    
        }

        remove(head.getElement());    
    }

    private int getTotal() {
        return total;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is your code compiling?

Comment: The method `remove(E)` is undefined. Could you post its code as well?

Comment: @SMA is compiling fine. Everything works except the clear method. But it is compiling.

Comment: @Turing85 I left off a few methods so that it wont be too much to read. I can add the other methods if you want me to?

Comment: @code since the method is used within `clear()`, it might be important for us to see it...

Comment: @Turing85 But that remove method is already part of my code?

Comment: @code you have a method `remove(int)`, but no method `remove(E)`

Comment: @Turing85 opps sorry about that. I will be reediting now.

Comment: Is it not enough for `clear()` to release `head` and `tail`, set `total` to 0, and let the garbage collector take care of the rest? Like what your constructor does?

Comment: @bali182 I am not sure what you mean? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @code he means to simply set `head = null` and `total = 0` in `clear()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `clear` method, I don't see that you do any per element cleanup, and the return type is `void`, so all you want is an empty list. The easiest way is to simply clear everything, like in the constructor:

```
public void clear() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null; 
    this.total = 0;
}
```

Another comment:

in `contains`, you do

```
while (head.getNext() != null) {
        head = head.getNext();

        if (head.getElement() == data) {
            System.out.println(head);                
            return true;                               
        }             
    }
```

which may have two problems (where the first applies to the entire class),

1. you compare with `== data` which compares references, where you probably want to compare values with `.equals(data)`

**Edit:** I.e.  `n.getElement().equals(data)` instead of  `n.getElement() == data`.

(Or, if `n` and `data` may be `null`, something like `(data != null ? data.equals(n.getElement()) : data == n.getElement())`

2. you use the attribute `head` as the scan variable which modifies the state of the list. Do you really want that?

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you elaborate on what I need to change on the contains method? Are you saying that I need to override the equals method?

Comment: @code check my answer for a link which elaborates the difference between `==` and `equals`.

Comment: @code no, simply use `.equals` instead of `==` if you want value comparison. Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises when you delete the last element within `clear`: `remove(head.getElement());`. For some reason, you first remove the `head` and then the `tail`. But when calling `removeLast`, you use the `head` (which is already `null`). Within `removeLast` this is the line, which causes the `NullPointerException`: `nodeBefore.setNext(null);`.
My advice would be to write the `clear()` method as @bali182 has suggested:

```
public void clear() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = head;
    this.total = 0;
}
```

One advice: if you are writing methods to search or delete entries, you should never use `==` when dealing with objects (or even better: don't use `==` at all when dealing with objects). You may want to read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion).

Answer (score 0):

From within clear method, you are calling `remove(head.getElement());` meaning you are trying to call LinkedList's remove method. And since you are overriding each functionality and so is add, you don't maintain internal state of LinkedList and hence you get exception. Code in remove is:

```
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (o==null) {
        for (Entry<E> e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next) {
            if (e.element==null) {
```

So here since you are not using functionality of LinkedList, header would be null and doing `header.next` would return NullPointerException.

Comment: OP is implementing a custum interface `LinkedList`. OP is not extending `LinkedList`. Therefore, OP does not have a method `remove(E)`

Comment: I don't think I understand? I already overridden my interface class method remove() and it works properly.

Comment: You implemented remove without any argument, but in reality you are calling it with one element `remove(head.getElement());`. So either you redefine remove method to accept one parameter or you change the call to remove without any argument.

Comment: @SMA `remove(int)` has an argument, but the wrong type. `removeFirst()` and `removeLast()` have no arguments. There is no method `remove()`

Comment: Your getElement returns a generic type element and not int `public E getElement() {

            return element;
        }`

Comment: You have tick below vote count on left side of my answer. If this has helped, tick it, so others can benefit of it.